# Работа с Event в VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic

Имею два класс `MainView` и `TerminlisteCollectionView`.
Второй как `Control` добавлен в первый.
Пытаюсь из второго класса, вызвать `Sub` в первом, с помощью `Event` при нажатии на кнопку

TerminlisteCollectionView.Class

```
Public Event KopfzeileWerkeinstellungen()

Private Sub WerkseinstellungButton_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As ItemClickEventArgs) Handles WerkseinstellungButton.ItemClick

      RaiseEvent KopfzeileWerkeinstellungen()

    End Sub
```

MainView.Class

```
Public WithEvents WerkeinstellungenEvent As Terminliste.Views.TerminlisteCollectionView.TerminlisteCollectionView

Public Sub Kopfzeile_Werkeinstellungen() Handles WerkeinstellungenEvent.KopfzeileWerkeinstellungen

    MessageBox.Show("Test")

  End Sub
```

Дальше `RaiseEvent` ничего не выполняется.

Comment: Брррр. Зачем парлефрансе названия методов? Жесть.

Comment: Зачем Control заворачивать в другой класс?

Comment: если актуально ссылку на полный пример, проект, попробую помочь.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь могу загрузить проект, но завтра. Он на DevExpress

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь https://wetransfer.com/downloads/2af065d859c083d3b2537fc57314557d20191202105232/d0eb9b7c491fcc4bfb92513647c6afc520191202105232/f69374